# Deploy Software using active directory without remote login

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, deployment

I'm looking for a way to deploy a package(Maybe MSI) trough the Active directory, I know it's possible, but as I know it requires a remote login on the servers in order to download the package and install it automatically.

Is there any document to do it?

Comment: Umm... No. Have a read here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/816102

Answer (score 1):

Joeqwerty is right on with that link.

The only you may want to double check is the permissions on the folder/file where your computers will be pulling the package from.

Good luck

**EDIT**
In terms of deploying software through AD, I would suggest this is the best way to go about it. As Joeqwerty mentioned earlier though, if you have other avenues available to you like System Center or PSExec, those will work as well. If you don't have these additional utilities available to you, a good command line - based utility built into win 7 is WMIC. Check out the technet link for that as well.

Comment: So, is it possible to do the deploy without need to do a login on the remote server?

Comment: yes, but not with active directory.  You can use SCCM or perhaps psexec once you have it packaged,

Comment: There is an option to install a .msi directly from AD GPM (I'm working off memory here, so bear with me) Computer settings --> Software Settings --> Software Installation

Comment: Note: I could use some clarification what you mean by "login" to a remote server. Since the .msi file will be on a pre-defined network location which will be accessed when the policy is applied, does this count as "login" to a remote server?

Comment: I mean by login that the user needs to open a remote desktop session(Graphical Session).

Comment: Fernando: If that is what you mean by login, then no. Once the GPO is applied to the right OU it should be deployed automatically (by computer SYSTEM account if going by computer settings). No other interaction is required by the end user at this point once you have fully troubleshot permissions (note the Local SYSTEM account is going to be used to install the software if you decide to go through  Group Policy).